# PHP merge and reorder multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 PHP arrays that look like this..

```
$array1
--------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 64
            [1] => Apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => Pear
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Raisin
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => Grape
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => Banana
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Orange
        )
)

$array2
--------
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => Pear
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => Banana
        )

)
```

I want to merge the arrays together but put the matching items from $array2 at the top so the result would look like this...

```
$array3
-------
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => Pear
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => Banana
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 64
            [1] => Apple
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Raisin
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => Grape
        )


    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Orange
        )
)
```

I'm not sure how to approach, should I merge the two first and then try and do some ordering, or is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: All of your arrays are invalid, they all have the same index (0).

Comment: Looks like you have added the wrong example. Can't be the same index for all `0`

Comment: Just create your *result array* and insert the 2nd array inside before the 1st one ? Also, your keys are wrong (all the indexes are `0`)

Comment: Key of the array is unique. In your case it's 0 everywhere.

Comment: Copy and paste error!  Have updated OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the 2nd array and then a rest of the 1st array

```
array_merge($arr2, array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, function($i1, $i2) {return $i1[0]-$i2[0];}));
```

Comment: I'm getting Array to string conversion error, I guess this is because it is a multidimensional array?

Comment: my bad. Look now

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help.  All makes sense now